How to route between three containers connected by two networks in series
I'm running into some issues with routing between docker networks. Hence, I broke the problem down into a simpler case but it is still not working. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

The Setup
node-one <---network-one---> node-two <---network-two---> node-three




Network
Subnet config




network-one
10.14.14.0/24


network-two
192.168.124.0/24






Node
IPs




node-one
10.14.14.3


node-two
10.14.14.2 and 192.168.124.123


node-three
192.168.124.2




I want to ping node-three from node-one.
Hence, I set up the following routes:
On node-one:
ip route add 192.168.124.0/24 via 10.14.14.2

On node-three:
ip route add 10.14.14.0/24 via 192.168.124.123

Everything else should be set up by docker.
I put my full configuration here:



File
Link




./docker-compose.yml
https://pastebin.com/raw/u4yHWB3b


./build-files/node/Dockerfile
https://pastebin.com/raw/3qy0pnh3


./build-files/node/docker-entrypoint.sh
https://pastebin.com/raw/Mn91zP1z


./build-files/node/spin.sh
https://pastebin.com/raw/h0DisTdv



The Results
Unfortunately, I can not ping node-three from node-one.
I.e. ping 192.168.124.2 just infinitely waits for a reply.
In fact, I get the same problem even when pinging just ping 192.168.124.123.
Tcpdump reveals that node-two is receiving the ping, and is also replying
to it, but apparently the reply never reaches node-one.
# tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:00:40.798963 IP network-debugging-node-one-1.network-debugging_network-one > d088c96b42f9: ICMP echo request, id 120, seq 1, length 64
12:00:40.798975 IP d088c96b42f9 > network-debugging-node-one-1.network-debugging_network-one: ICMP echo reply, id 120, seq 1, length 64

Do you know what could be causing this?
Thank you in advance.

Can node-two and node-three ping (receive replies from) node-one though? Btw, did you mean node-one can ping node-two at 10.14.14.2?

Ah, good clarification question. The nodes can ping each other via the docker networks that directly connect them. I.e. node-one can ping node-two via 10.14.14.2, and vice-versa via 10.14.14.3.
Node-two can ping node-three via 192.168.124.2 and vice-versa via 192.168.124.123.

Apparently it was my firewall that was interfering with this.
I am sorry for wasting everyone's time with this post.
So I suppose the only learning here is to check the firewall first before spending a lot of time on debugging supposed routing problems.
Some more info: I am using NixOS and have its firewall set to enabled. After disabling the firewall configuration, the pings work.
Therefore, there must be some iptables rule that is generated by NixOS which is preventing the packets from crossing between the networks.

Edit: The problematic rules generated by the NixOS firewall can be found in the chain nixos-fw-rpfilter which is a target of the PREROUTING chain of the mangle table.
These rules are generated if the NixOS option networking.firewall.checkReversePath is enabled, which is the default.
Hence, a quick solution for NixOS users is to set this option to false.
However, I instead chose to add exception rules just for my use case.
I.e. I gave the bridge networks fixed names using com.docker.network.bridge.name in driver_opts, and then I added the following commands to networking.firewall.extraCommands:
networking.firewall.extraCommands = ''
  iptables -t mangle -I nixos-fw-rpfilter -i network-one -d 10.14.14.0/24 -j RETURN
  iptables -t mangle -I nixos-fw-rpfilter -i network-two -d 192.168.124.0/24 -j RETURN
'';

Similar commands can likely be applied for other types of firewalls interfering with the docker networks.

Might be worth mentioning that docker pulls in a kernel module called br_netfilter which would do nasty thing like applying L3 iptables (and even nftables) rules on L2 forwarding that occurs in bridges. (See the net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-* sysctls.)

Thank you for pointing this out! Indeed, disabling the net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-* sysctls is also sufficient for resolving the problem. However, it seems like docker partially depends on br_netfilter, so I am hesitant to disable it.
Instead, I was able to identify the problematic iptables rules generated by NixOS. I.e. NixOS appends a chain nixos-fw-rpfilter to the PREROUTING chain of the mangle table that drops the packets. These rules are generated if the NixOS option networking.firewall.checkReversePath is enabled, which is the default.
I'll update my answer accordingly,.
